# Creating custom air raid siren sound (User Tone) on Casio CTK-611

Tags: keyboard, synthesizer

I would like to create an air raid siren sound on the Casio CTK-611 keyboard (or a keyboard that works the same). The keyboard allows users to edit certain features of the pre-set instrument sounds to create custom instruments. For example, you can edit the amp envelope, attack rate, release rate, pitch envelope, pitch, level, touch sensitivity and pan - modifying the value for each of those elements.  I don't know how to ascertain what value of the Pitch Envelope (if that's the right element to look at) would set the sound to "slowly rising pitch."

I'd appreciate any direct instructions, guidance, or resources.